# JPA inheritance issue, why the generated query is different between wildfly10 and jboss7

Tags: jpa, inheritance, jboss7.x, wildfly-10

I am migrating a project from jboss7 to wildfly10. The strange thing is the generated query in jboss is different in wildfly10, that causes the tables structure have to be changed, but it is not expected.

```
public class BaseAnnotation implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6636704943305921427L;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="one")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class oneBaseAnnotation extends BaseAnnotation {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "baseAnnotationSequencer")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "baseAnnotationSequencer", sequenceName = "BASEANNOTATION_SEQ")
private Long id;

private String annotationType;
.....
}

@Entity
public class TwoStructureAnnotation extends oneBaseAnnotation {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5838272604038154615L;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name= "CSA_CS")
private List<TwoStructure> twoStructures = new ArrayList<TwoStructure>();

public TwoStructureAnnotation() {
    setAnnotationType("Two Structure");
}
.....
}

public class..... {
   protected List<T> createQuery(int first, int pageSize,
        List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String> filters,
        String joinField) {
    // Setup
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getObjectEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = (CriteriaQuery<T>) cb.createQuery();
    Root<A> annotationRoot = criteria.from(TwoStructureAnnotation.class);
    ListJoin<A, T> joinRoot = annotationRoot.joinList("twosStructures");
    Predicate restrictions = cb.conjunction();

    // Filter
    filters.putAll(this.getBaseFilter());
    restrictions = cb.and(restrictions,
            createGlobalFilter(filters, joinRoot, cb));

    restrictions = cb.and(restrictions,
            cb.equal(annotationRoot, annotation));
    ...
    // Query creation
    criteria.where(restrictions);
    criteria.select(joinRoot);

    // Restrict Returns
    TypedQuery<T> returnQuery = getObjectEntityManager().createQuery(
            criteria);
    returnQuery.setFirstResult(first);
    returnQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);

    List<T> results = returnQuery.getResultList();

    ....}
```

The query below, the different that the key in the `inner join` on table CSA_CS. I have no idea why, please suggest me, thank you.

--in Jboss7

```
select * from
( select
    crystalstr2_.id as id1_43_,
    crystalstr2_.pdbEntry_id as pdbEntry_id3_43_,
    crystalstr2_.title as title2_43_ 
from
    ONE crystalstr0_ 
inner join
    CSA_CS crystalstr1_ 
        on crystalstr0_.id=crystalstr1_.ONE_id 
inner join
    TwoStructure crystalstr2_ 
        on crystalstr1_.crystalStructures_id=crystalstr2_.id 
where
    crystalstr0_.DTYPE='TwoStructureAnnotation' 
    and 1=1 
    and 1=1 
    and crystalstr0_.id=? ) 
where
rownum <= ?
```

---In wildfly10

```
select
 * 
from
 ( select
     crystalstr2_.id as id1_36_,
     crystalstr2_.pdbEntry_id as pdbEntry_id3_36_,
     crystalstr2_.title as title2_36_ 
 from
     ONE crystalstr0_ 
 inner join
     CSA_CS crystalstr1_ 
         on crystalstr0_.id=crystalstr1_.TWOStructureAnnotation_id 
 inner join
     TwoStructure crystalstr2_ 
         on crystalstr1_.crystalStructures_id=crystalstr2_.id 
 where
     crystalstr0_.DTYPE='TwoStructureAnnotation' 
     and 1=1 
     and 1=1 
     and crystalstr0_.id=? ) 
 where
 rownum <= ?
```

Tables:

```
table-TWOSTRUCTURE
ID
TITLE

table-CSA_CS
ONE_ID
CRYSTALSTRUCTURES_ID

table-ONE
DTYPE
ID
ANNOTATIONTYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

JBoss7 ships hibernate 4.x and wildfly 10 ships hibernate 5. In hibernate 5, Oracle is implemented  'inner join'. If you use Oracle10gDialect, then 
Oracle10gDialect added support for ANSI joins. Subclasses (e.g. Oracle12cDialect) inherit this functionality.

Comment: thank you reply. the issue right now is the key id name in different server has different column name. the inner join is same between 2 servers.